# How to ensure that a google user on app engine has a youtube account

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube, account

Is there a way on google app engine to check if a google account is linked with a youtube account? As far as I know, there is no guarantee that a user whose nickname() method returns a certain name, has the same nickname  on youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way for an app to make that check.